# How to open blackberry native browser from browse field app for external link

Tags: blackberry

I am working on an app for blackberry(jre 6.o & os 7.x) using browse field and app is working fine. One thing I want that, when click on a link in app and link url(domain) is different from the url which is invoked in app using browse field, open link in native blackberry browser. Please help me how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us something that you have tried but failed to get working?

Comment: could you please explain this again with an example or something, so that we approach this the right way. One certain thing we can do is, open any link from native BB browser.

Comment: @stack_ved Look, e.g. I am opening url like www.google.com in browse field. It will open browse field embedded browser. If on google.com any link goes outside google.com should open in BB native browser not all links.

Comment: could you try using BrowserSession browserSession = browser.getDefaultSession();   browserSession.displayPage(url); if you have the authority to decide if a particular url is to be called on BB native or not.

Comment: @stack_ved this is the problem, how I can decide it, which work in both conditions. Thanks.

Comment: @limelights do u want to see code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend ProtocolController class and override its handleNavigationRequest() method to do a custom implementation.

usage-
oBrowserField.getConfig().setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER,
                new CustomProtocolController(oBrowserField));

Where oBrowserField is BrowserField instance
And CustomProtocolController is custom class extending ProtocolController

Comment: can u please example code.I have tried this as u suggested but not able to achieve the target. Used code given [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-open-links-in-actual-browser/td-p/468721).Thanks.

Comment: What problem you are getting. The link you posted seems to be having the required code snippet. That should be it to test it.

public void handleNavigation(BrowserFieldRequest request)
{
if(request.getURL().equals("Your URL"))
{
 InputConnection oInputConnection = handleResourceRequest(request);
 oBrowserField.displayContent(oInputConnection, request.getURL());
}
else
{                    
 BrowserSession browser = Browser.getDefaultSession();
 browser.displayPage(request.getURL());                   
}
}